# store a username in a quick.db database

Tags: discord.js, last.fm, quick.db

I want to store a word that was provided as an arg after a command from a user in a quick.db database. I'm pretty new to quick.db and it's my first time using it. Can someone help? Thank you sm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure how your commands are formatted, if the following doesn't work, please comment!

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
if(!user) return message.channel.send('You must mention a message!');

const message = args.splice(1).join(` `);
if(!message) return message.channel.send(`You must provide a message`);
db.set('message' + user.id, message);
message.channel.send(`Successfully set the ${user.tag}\'s message as: ${message}`)
```

The first db requirement defines db, the user is the first mentioned user inside of a message.

```js
const message = args.splice(1).join(` `);
if(!message) return message.channel.send(`You must provide a message`);
```

The `const message` defines the message you are receiving, it splices the user and joins the string with spaces. It prevents errors by checking if the message exists, if it doesn't it returns.

```js
db.set('message' + user.id, message);
message.channel.send(`Successfully set the ${user.tag}\'s message as: ${message}`)
```

This part just sets the message into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example if you wanted to warn someone with a reason, you could do;

```
let db = require('quick.db')

let user = message.mentions.users.first()

let reason = args.splice(1).join(" ")

db.set(`warn_${message.author.id}`, reason)
```

This will set the args for "reason" to "warn_*the author who use the warn command's id*"